# create my own blob detection in C

Tags: c, computer-vision, computer-science, blobs

I'm doing a little school project and for that I need to detect a white paper sheet. I tried to see if I can do the blob detection with OpenCV, but OpenCV is not my area.
I want to do my own blob detection for the sheet. I tried to search for examples, but I can't find anything.

What I want my blob detector to do is: detect the white paper sheet, then give the coordinates of the 4 corners of the sheet, and then, draw a polygon over it.

The blob detector must detect the white sheet even if there are drawings inside the sheet.
Any help could be great, because I just got one week to finish this.

Comment: In stead of searching for examples, you should try to figure the logic yourself. Assuming the sheet has not been rotated, simply loop over the pixels column by column from both sides and row by row from the top and bottom. Detect the first row / column containing enough white pixels to be sure the sheet has been reached. Drawing the polygon should now be straight forward